# How to address twang package warnings in mnps function

Tags: r, propensity-scores, weighted-regression

I am using `twang` package as I have an analysis where I want to compare 3 categories and want to compute propensity scores to include as weights in the regression analysis. I have $9338$ subjects and use $5$ predictors in the `mnps` function, so I would be surprised that overfitting would be an issue. Unfortunately, I cannot provide the dataset as it is confidential data, but basically, I don't get any warning or error when I run:

```
mnps.IU <- mnps(Exp_category ~ Sex + SES_Decile + Parity + 
               Maternal_smoking + IndigenousStatus,
               data=dataset_name,
               estimand="ATE",
               verbose=FALSE,
               stop.method=c("es.mean","ks.mean"),
               interaction.depth=2,
               n.trees=10000)
```

Nor when using the `bal.table` function also from `twang` package on the `mnps` object. However, when using `summary()` on this object `summary(mnps.IU)`, I have an output that gives me values for `max.std.eff.sz`, `min.p`, `max.ks`, `min.ks.pval`, `stop.method`, `n`, `EDD.es.mean` and `ESS:ks.mean`, but at the same type I get several warnings of the type:

```
In FUN(newX[, i], ...): no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
```

I have no missing values in the variables included in the `mnps` function.

Does anyone know what could cause these warnings and how they can be assessed?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please have a look at the [tour](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour). We value questions that are to the point and include only relevant information. You do not have to thank anyone. Also note that questions primarily about programming are unfortunately off topic here

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really the appropriate site for this kind of question, since it's a programming question and not a statistics question. In the future, use StackOverflow to ask questions about debugging software.

This warning occurs when supplying no non-`NA` arguments to `min()`. This is not something you can correct; it is a coding error inside `twang`. You can probably ignore this warning, but I would be cautious about trusting the output of `summary()` in case this indicates an underlying bug that is more serious.

I'm going to plug my package `WeightIt`, which also performs PS weighting using GBM (among other methods) and does not currently suffer from this bug. The syntax is the same as `twang`'s.

Comment: Thank you Noah, I am new to these forums and was not sure if statistical software issues belonged here, but I will be careful in the future. I will check WeightIt, so I understand it can also perform PS weighting when there are 3 exposures/treatments?